# Visual Studio IDE how to build and view changes in browser without opening a new tab or window?

Tags: iis, visual-studio, webpage

I'm following the tutorial on 
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc. And whenever code change are made, the guy simply re-builds, and refreshes the browser tab to view any changes. It doesn't work with the setting I have within Visual Studios 2013. I need to re-build, and click Run again, which opens up a new tab in my browser.

Comment: He does exactly what you describe, he likely just hit debug which by default will compile and run in Vs

Comment: @Op, I recommend rephrasing your title/post to emphasize that you are asking about the operation of the IDE, not the code within it, to prevent close votes from folks who misunderstand and assume you are asking a programming question.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F5` is the default keyboard shortcut for Debug mode.

Comment: @Ramhound, Perhaps its changed in the very latest version, but in VS2003-VS2013, F5 is debug, and Ctrl + F5 is "Start without debugging". pull down the Build menu to confirm the correct keys for your version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructor is Running the application (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) initially, rather than debugging it.

When a debugger is attached (eg you launch the application with <kbd>F5</kbd> or by hitting the green play arrow), you have to stop debugging before you can rebuild, and when you debug again, or restart, the changed version will open in a new tab.

When you run an application without debugging however, you can rebuild at any time (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>). a new browser tab/window is not launched, but the code in the IISExpress instance is updated, so when you refresh the browser, you see the changes.

Additionally, many changes to the application do not require a rebuild at all. for instance changing CSS, javascript, or other purely markup information. In those cases, you can just save and refresh. I do caution you however to only do this for tweaking CSS, as you may introduce problems in other parts of the code, and not notice them until much later. rebuilding is always a safe bet.